# Button click using selenium in Python Error : Element is not clickable at point (579, 267)

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following webpage `https://bitbucket.org`. I want to add `ssh key` to the bitbucket's deployment key using selenium. I want to click `Add key` button using selenium driver.

[image]

Here is the attached HTML of the page. I am able to add key to the page using command

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//textarea[@name='key'])[2]").send_keys('key added')
```

I am not able to press `Add key` button through the commands I have tried

```
1. driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add key')]").click()
2. driver.find_element_by_tag_name("footer").find_element_by_tag_name("div").find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add key')]").click()
```

It is not able to find the element with xpath in command 1 and it is showing error for the second command : `Element is not clickable at point (579, 267) Other element would receive the click: <textarea class=" textarea long-field" cols="40" columns="40" id="id_key" name="key" placeholder="Paste your key here..." rows="8"></textarea>` 
After trying a lot of options, I am not able to figure out where I am wrong. Please help me find the error.

Comment: Do not provide `html` code sample as an image file. Add same to ticket as text

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate moving to the button using `move_to_element` from [ActionChains](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html)

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add key')]")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

> Edit

You can also try to click with JavaScript

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementByXPath(\'' + //button[contains(text(), 'Add key')] + '\').click()")
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (579, 267)

Comment: @VivekPuri Try to use actions click `actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()`

Comment: Error : `Element is not clickable at point (579, 267). Other element would receive the click: <textarea class=" textarea long-field" cols="40" columns="40" id="id_key" name="key" placeholder="Paste your key here..." rows="8"></textarea>`

Comment: @VivekPuri I added another solution

Comment: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Message: expected expression, got end of script
Stacktrace:
    at handleEvaluateEvent (https://bitbucket.org/vivek-puri/bit_bicket_repo_1/admin/deploy-keys/:69)

Answer (score 0):

One point we need to pay attention to the resolution of test environment. This issue happen when to want to perform an action *outside* the current visible screen

1 - We need to ensure the same resolution for scripting and executing scripts

2 - Scroll to visible element part of the screen before taking any actions

Here's my sample code on C#, you could edit it into python

```
    public void Click(IWebElement obj)
    {
        // Scroll the browser to the element's Y position
        (Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript(string.Format("window.scrollTo({1}, {0});", obj.Location.Y, obj.Location.X));

        // Click the element
        obj.Click();
    }
```

It's not quite an answer, however I want to post it separately here for more convenient view/look